# Why is cross-entropy increasing with accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-entropy

I'm making an implementation of the softmax regression and I'm struggling to understand the nature behind the problem of increasing value of Cross-Entropy: $H(y_i, p_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^C y_i log(p_i)$, along with an increasing accuracy:

[image]

This is utmost confusing to me, because there's no class imbalance:

[image]

I am not entirely sure whether the **sample size** of $N = 112$ is at fault. I will appreciate any help on the matter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the x axis in your plots?

Comment: You can refer to this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42599/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-accuracy-and-the-loss-in-deep-learning/42600#42600

Comment: Philosophically, the model gained a higher accuracy but a lower confidence. If you choose the 1-0 loss function for a binary classification task then loss and accuracy are the same.

Comment: Got it, thanks @TranKhanh